# MongoDB: How to perform a second match using the results (an array of ObjectIds) of the previous match in aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection called `users` with documents that look like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('123'),
  username: "abc",
  avatar: "avatar/long-unique-random-string.jpg",
  connections: [ObjectId('abc'), ObjectId('xyz'), ObjectId('lmn'), ObjectId('efg')]
}
```

This document belongs to the `users` collection.

What I want to do:

- First, find one document from the users' collection that matches `_id` -> '123'.
- Project the `connections` field received from step 1, which is an array of ObjectIds of other users within the same collection.
- Find all documents of users from the array field projected in step 2.
- Project and return an array of only the `username` and `avatar` of all those users from step 3.

While I know that I can do this in two separate queries. First using `findOne` which returns the friends array. Then, using `find` with the results of `findOne` to get all the corresponding usernames and avatars.

But, I would like to do this in one single query, using the aggregation pipeline.

What I want to know, is it even possible to do this in one query using aggregation?

If so, what would the query look like?

What, I currently have:

```
await usersCollection
  .aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: new ObjectId(userId) } },
    { $project: { ids: "$connections" } },
    { $match: { _id: { $in: "ids" } } },
    {
      $project: {
        username: "$username",
        avatar: { $ifNull: ["$avatar", "$$REMOVE"] },
      },
    },
  ])
  .toArray()
```

I know this is wrong because each aggregation stage receives the results from the previous stage. So, the second match cannot query on the entire users' collection, as far as I know.

I'm using MongoDB drivers for nodeJS. And I would like to avoid `$lookup` for possible solutions.

Comment: You can try the "self join" operation - that is use `$lookup` on the same _users_ collection.

Comment: @prasad_ I want to avoid `$lookup` because it's not supported on shared collections.

Comment: What is _shared collections_?

Comment: @prasad_ My bad. The autocorrect changed the word. I meant sharded collections.